Isn't one user overseeding during the private beta?
When it comes to the question, one user is seeding a lot of questions.
I am happy that he puts a lot of effort and enthusiasm. However, I have serious doubts if it is not overdoing. I.e. high number of under-elaborated questions posted by one individual (in my opinion) is likely to be rather a bad start, because:

it makes things less democratic,
it makes a flood of unanswered questions,
some of the questions are often similar and requiring work to make them more precise and better asked. 

I refrained for downvoting as it is not a good idea to downvote at the very beginning and most of the questions have a great potential to be very good ones, given effort to clarify and elucidate them.
What do you think about that?

I appreciate your feedback. Sorry for giving the appearance of posting too many bad questions - I was in a rush in trying to move all of my open (unanswered) questions from Quora and Reddit, so I didn't have the time to put more thought into them on the first day (as I was still trying to tweeze many of them from nooks and crannies of the two places). I'll try to improve some of them today and tomorrow.

Good man @InquilineKea. I think a lot of your questions are good at the core, and after cleanup will be a great fit for this site! Also, I think if you help us define the scope here on Meta before posting more, that's good also.

@InquilineKea: Glad to hear you appreciate the feedback. Nice having you on board!

@InquilineKea: I am very happy to hear that. And it is good that you have a lot of questions in mind. But... it would be nice to put quality before quantity (you don't need to ask everything in one day). If you want to get answers (and especially good ones), reducing number but improving content will be very beneficial. On a side note (actually more on aesthetics than the content) - try to avoid using * and " in titles. It will make them look more decent.

Okay - thanks for all the responses again! One thing - I just started editing a lot of my old questions, but my reputation (after editing) suddenly went down from 313 to 251. Does anyone know what happened?

Pitor I am closing this as "too localized" only because it was about a specific situation in the private beta which has now been resolved, and we're now in public beta. But please don't think this means this was a bad question to raise at the time!

Yes, he's overdoing it.
We haven't even defined the scope of this site yet and already we have a flood of questions from Reddit and Quora. And what really bothers me is that the questions as they're posted on cogsci.stackexchange.com are not formatted very well.
I am all for seeding the site, but in order for it to be done right two things need to happen:

We have to have a clearly defined scope of what is on- and off- topic.
The questions have to be posted as good Stack Exchange questions. They have to be more than just links to/blockquotes of questions on other sites.

If we don't do those two things we're not making the internet a better place, we're just becoming a link farm, and Joel will shut us down. I speak from experience, I've been on other private beats where this has happened before.
Please note I don't intend offense to InquilineKea or anyone else! I'm just trying to make the site better, and InquilineKea I respect your enthusiasm and understand you're trying to help the site get started also! I think with a little community guidance you can make some really great questions here. This question for example has the potential to be a great question, but as it now stands the body needs a lot of work.

Exactly. The problem isn't he is overdoing it perse, the problem is not enough effort went into the questions.

Down votes are there to indicate a question isn't very good, and hopefully also to refrain the user from continuing posting bad questions. I'm all for the down vote and don't see the problem with it.
Down voting doesn't mean the question should be closed. A question can have great potential, and if the user is serious about those questions he will edit them in order to get up votes instead of down votes.

+1, I even commented on a few that I was downvoting but would reverse when the problems were fixed.
